# Spark plug thread broke inside the engine

Tags: sparkplugs, cylinder-head

I took out the spark plug on the fourth cylinder and it appeared to have some metal on its thread I cleaned it out and put it back inside while tightening it the thread broke inside

[image]

The part in circle is what broke off, although the tip which is not connected to the threads is still there.

Now how do I deal with this problem? Do I have to take off the head and remove the bits and remove the plug?

Comment: Can you add a photo of the damaged plug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright I managed to remove it using a screw driver and hammering on it, I know this could have broken the threads inside but luckily it didn't. I used penetrating fluid to help loosen it a bit more. The engine was sputtering after installing the new spark plug because I add a little bit excess of penetrating fluid but after it cleared up it ran fine.

Comment: Right on, glad you got it out.    +1 for success